# How to group by and get same result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have days column which I called with :

```
select days from discount
```

and the result is like this :
[group by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Rkj.png)

What I want is to add group by and get the same result as that picture. How do get the same result with group by? if I add group by days, it gives me the error message "could not identify an equality operator for type JSON"

My expected result is row like this just like select days from discount output result:

```
["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
```

Comment: What do you expect your result should be? Please add more clarity for output results and your data structure.

Comment: Add create table script, sample datas and expected result.

Comment: @Pooya, I added expected result

Comment: @suns : You give the expected result but what is the structure of the table ? Post sample datas...

Comment: Do you want the group by to give you the unique string: just one row?

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: @tinazmu just one row

Comment: So would `select distinct days from discount` give you what you want?

Comment: Can you cast to text : select days::text from discount group by days::text

Comment: @tinazmu, you are correct -> select days::text from discount group by days::text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Json to text (cast), then you can:

```
select days::text
from discount 
group by 
days::text
```